# Can I use a specific element inside the groupby functions instead of using column name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Im trying to use groupby function, is there a way to use a specific element rather than the column name. Example of code.

```
df.groupby(['Month', 'Place'])['Number'].sum()
```

This is what I want to do.

```
df.groupby(['April', Place'])['Number'].sum()
```

Comment: please provide an example, likely you do not want (only) a groupby but a filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need filter your DataFrame before:

```
df.loc[df['Month'].eq('April')].groupby('Place')['Number'].sum()
#df[df['Month'].eq('April')].groupby('Place')['Number'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass as many columns to groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'x', 1], ['a', 'x', 2], ['b', 'y',3], ['b', 'z',4]])
df.columns = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
df.groupby(['c1', 'c2'])['c3'].mean()
```

resuls in

```
c1  c2
a   x     1.5
b   y     3.0
    z     4.0
```